# JavaScript and __proto__ - what browsers use it?

Tags: javascript, prototype

What web browsers use the `__proto__`? [Mozilla states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Inheritance_Revisited) that:

> Note that `__proto__` may not be available in JavaScript versions other than that in Mozilla.

Comment: You could enclose `__proto__` in backticks `\`` for the formatting.

Comment: StackOverflow formatting only sucks if you don't take the time to understand how it works.

Comment: No backticks key on azerty keyboards FWIW

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Click [here](http://browsershots.org/http://artistoex.net/prototype.html) for your answer.

**Details**

The most general way would be to test this page in different browsers:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function a() {}
      if ( (new a).__proto__ === a.prototype )
          alert('supported');
    </script>

  </head>
</html>
```

It alerts if a browser supports `__proto__`.   I've submitted it to [browsershots.org](http://browsershots.org/http://artistoex.net/prototype.html), which will create screenshots of the page in many different browsers.  Thus, you should see--by means of the alert message--which browser does support it.

Comment: Thank you!  To sum up, it does not work on IE, Safari < 5 and Opera < 10.50.

Comment: The link is no longer active.  Anyone know about IE9?

Comment: I just tested this in IE9 and IE10.  It does not work in IE9, but does work in IE10.

Answer (score 7):

The [Browser Security Handbook](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part1#Browser-side_Javascript) has a table showing which browsers expose `__proto__`.

Currently, those browsers are:

- Firefox 2
- Firefox 3
- Safari
- Chrome
- Android

Those excluded:

- IE 6, 7, 8
- Opera

Answer (score 3):

The end of the sentence you posted is `See below for workarounds.`, where there is a discussion on an alternative method `extends()` that uses `super.prototype`:

```
function extend(child, super){  
  for (var property in super.prototype) {  
    if (typeof child.prototype[property] == "undefined")  
      child.prototype[property] = super.prototype[property];  
  }  
  return child;  
}
```

Comment: I know, but I want to know what web browsers are supporting `__proto__`. Depending on the answer, I may not even need that kind of functionality.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd copy properties from one object into another... This defeats the purpose of the powerful prototypal inheritance built into JS.

Answer (score 0):

*This is not direct answer to the question but it may help for those who wanna know the prototype of the object instance (this is for what `__proto__` is often used).* All modern browsers (including IE9) supports [`getPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) which can be used to determine the object's prototype. The irony of fate is that some still actual browsers like IE7 and IE8 that don't support `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)` don't support `obj.__proto__` as well. For those browsers you can use `obj.constructor.prototype`. However it is a bit dangerous because this property can be redefined.