# Node.js - Best method for emitting events from modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, eventemitter

I've been playing around with the `EventEmitter`, but I'm confused about how exactly I should implement it from a module. I've seen a few different ways, and they all seem to work. Here are a few I've seen:

From [here](https://gist.github.com/833401):

```
var Twitter = function() {...};

Twitter.prototype = new events.EventEmitter;
```

But then in ["Mastering Node"](http://visionmedia.github.com/masteringnode/book.html) they do it this way:

```
function Dog(name) {
  this.name = name;
  EventEmitter.call(this);
}

Dog.prototype.__proto__ = EventEmitter.prototype;
```

(why would you need to .call it?)

And then in my own code I tried yet another way:

```
function Class() {}

Class.prototype = EventEmitter.prototype;
```

They're all just inheriting from EventEmitter in their own way, so wouldn't the simplest solution be the best?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should use the `__proto__` style of inheritance. [This assumes you're coding solely for Node, or only supporting your favorite browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082791/javascript-and-proto-what-browsers-use-it).  Also, `Base.call(this)` is necessary if you care about any logic in the constructor of your base prototype.

The `__proto__` technique to reference a base prototype will ensure that the `instanceof` operator correctly identifies instances of the prototype.  The `.constructor` property of instances of the child *class* will reference the constructor you expect it to.  It also has the benefit of not instantiating a new instance of the base prototype.

The `new Base()` style will also ensure that `instanceof` gives you the correct answer, but it will run the constructor for Base.  Generally not an issue, but can be problematic if your base constructor has required arguments.  It will also set the `.constructor` property to the base constructor, [not the descendant constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650764/how-does-proto-differ-from-constructor-prototype).

Setting the prototype of your *class* to the prototype of the base *class* will confuse `instanceof` as any descendants of the base will also appear to be instances of the child.

Clear as mud, right? This example should help:

```
// Base constructor.
// A, B, and C will inherit from Base.
function Base() {
    this.name = 'base';
}

// new Base() style
function A() {
    Base.call(this);
}
A.prototype = new Base();

// __proto__ = prototype style
function B() {
    Base.call(this);
}
B.prototype.__proto__ = Base.prototype;

// prototype = protoype style
function C() {
    Base.call(this);
}
C.prototype = Base.prototype;

// create instances
var a = new A();
var b = new B();
var c = new C();

// are we who we think we are?
console.assert(a instanceof A);
console.assert(b instanceof B);
console.assert(c instanceof C);
// so far so good

// do we respect our elders?
console.assert(a instanceof Base);
console.assert(b instanceof Base);
console.assert(c instanceof Base);
// we have respect

// test to see that Base.call(this)
// functioned as expected
console.assert(a.name == 'base');
console.assert(b.name == 'base');
console.assert(c.name == 'base');
// ok, good...

// but now things get weird
console.assert(a instanceof C);
console.assert(b instanceof C);
// that's not right! a is not C, b is not C!

// At least A and B do not confuse identities
console.assert(!(a instanceof B));
console.assert(!(b instanceof A));

console.assert(!(c instanceof A));
console.assert(!(c instanceof B));

// so we've determined that style C is no good.
// C confuses the inheritance chain.

// B is the winner.

// Why? Only B passes this test
console.assert(b.constructor == B);

// a and c's constructors actually point to the Base constructor
console.assert(a.constructor == Base);
console.assert(c.constructor == Base);

// Word B.
```

Comment: Wow thank you. I wish I could give more than one upvote for this answer.

Answer (score 20):

Node has a library function, util.inherits, that is slightly more straightforward than the accepted answer. Code below is modified from the [v0.8.12 docs](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor).

```
var util = require("util");
var events = require("events");

function MyStream() {
  events.EventEmitter.call(this);
}

util.inherits(MyStream, events.EventEmitter);
```

Comment: I have [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809786/different-ways-of-extending-classes-in-node-js) that is somewhat related to this. Would you mind looking at it?

Comment: Also could you explain `events.EventEmitter.call(this);` and why this is necessary or if its possible to disregard it?

Comment: @majidarif The short answer is that the call executes the EventEmitter function with the MyStream instance as the "this" variable, so it will go through all the EventEmitter initialization for MyStream instances. Hope that makes sense.