# Different ways of extending classes in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Extending prototypical classes in node.js or javascript in general. (js newb)

I was looking at the source-code of expressjs and saw [this](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/express.js):

```
var mixin = require('utils-merge'); 
....
mixin(app, proto);
mixin(app, EventEmitter.prototype);
```

`Utils-merge` seems like an external module. What are the difference of above and just doing something like:

```
var util = require('util');
....
util.inherit(app, proto);
util.inherit(app, EventEmitter);
```

And is this still trying to extend properties? I'm kind-a lost here:

```
app.request = { __proto__: req, app: app }; // what is the equivalent for this in util?
app.response = { __proto__: res, app: app };
```

If so, will that still work even if `util.inherit` is used?

```
app.request = util.inherit(app, req)
```

Or something like that? jshint says `__proto__` is depricated.

---

Additionally I also saw this?

```
var res = module.exports = {
  __proto__: http.ServerResponse.prototype
};
```

Could this be?

```
var res = module.exports = util.inherits...??
```

Comment: You can use `util.inherit` only once per constructor!

Comment: So is there any alternative to: `mixin(app, proto);
mixin(app, EventEmitter.prototype);`

Comment: What exactly is `app`? What is `proto`?

Comment: or an alternative to this: `app.request = { __proto__: req, app: app };` because `__proto__` the jshint says deprecated.

Comment: @Bergi it can be found [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/express.js). Is part of the express framework lib.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I was looking at the source-code of expressjs

You might also want to have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23626625/1048572) about how `app` is supposed to work.

> What are the differences between `utils-merge`
>   as above and just doing something like:
>
> ```
> var util = require('util');
> ....
> util.inherit(app, proto);
> util.inherit(app, EventEmitter);
> ```

They're doing totally different things:

> **[utils-merge](https://www.npmjs.org/package/utils-merge)**
>   *Merges the properties from a source object into a destination object.*
>
> **[util.inherits](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor)**
>
> *Inherit the prototype methods from one constructor into another. The prototype of constructor will be set to a new object created from
>   superConstructor.*

Also read [their](https://github.com/jaredhanson/utils-merge/blob/master/index.js#l1) [sources](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/95dbb6bf647d90947c0c738533dadf391559be98/lib/util.js#L615)!

`app` (while being a function for odd reasons) is not a constructor, but is supposed to be a (plain) object - an **instance** made by `createApplication`. So there's no way to do "class inheritance" here. And you cannot use `utils.inherits` multiple times on the same constructor anyways, as it does *overwrite* the `.prototype` property of it.

Instead, that `mixin` function will simply copy all the properties from `proto` and then all properties from `EventEmitter.prototype` to the `app` object.

> And is this still trying to extend properties? I'm kind-a lost here:
>
> ```
> app.request = { __proto__: req, app: app }; // what is the equivalent for this in util?
> app.response = { __proto__: res, app: app };
> ```

Use the native [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) function for this:

```
app.request = Object.create(req);
app.request.app = app;
app.response = Object.create(res);
app.response.app = app;
```

> If so, will that still work even if `util.inherit` is used?
>
> ```
> app.request = util.inherit(app, req) // Or something like that?
> ```

No, really not.

> jshint says `__proto__` is depricated.

Yes, you should use `Object.create` instead. But the [nonstandard `__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) will probably be kept for compatibility.

> Additionally I also saw this?
>
> ```
> var res = module.exports = {
>   __proto__: http.ServerResponse.prototype
> };
> ```
>
> Could this be?
>
> ```
> var res = module.exports = util.inherits...??
> ```

No, again that's a case for `Object.create`:

```
var res = module.exports = Object.create(http.ServerResponse.prototype);
```

Comment: One more question, how about this? `this.request.__proto__ = parent.request;`

Comment: What is `parent`? How was `this.request` initially created? But no, [you should really not change the `__proto__`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23809148/1048572) after an object was created.

Comment: It's on the expressjs application code. I dont really understand all the inheritance all over the code.

Comment: Ah, you mean [this file](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/application.js). Yes, they're really doing ugly things there, apparently with the aim to extend the native object without modifying them. But, why do you *need* to understand all the code? Just use the library.

Comment: because [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24869267/understanding-expressjs-base-code). Technically trying to create a simple similar one for the net/tcp protocol. Instead of http.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ES6` in Node.js.

```
class myClass() {
  this.hi = function(){"hello"};

}

class myChild extends myClass() {

}

var c = new myChild(); c.hi(); //hello
```

Comment: Though this would require the `--harmony` right? Also I'm still confused if I would rewrite their code to newer specs, how it would look. I believe __proto__ wouldnt be there anymore because node.js has util.inherit now. But i cant understand how to write it with util.

Comment: If at all, the `class` keyword would need to be lowercased. I also fail to see how this answers the question.

Comment: also classes are not implemented in v8 yet

Comment: But you can shim theme with Traceur no?