# JavaScript's anonymous objects prototype

Tags: javascript, oop, scope, closures, prototype

I learn JavaScript's "OOP" models, and looking forward to an advice how can I code around some problem I faced. (I will use the terminology "instance" later however now I know there's no instances in JavaScript.) Consider the following code:

```
function Class1(){
   this.locvar1 = "locvar1";
   this.locvar2 = "locvar2";
}

function Class2(){
    this.set = function(){     
        this.locvar1 = "ch_locvar1";
    }
} 
Class2.prototype = new Class1;

//we'll get two instances from Class2
var x = new Class2();
x.set();  // we'll change the x's field with that (hoping that)

var y = new Class2();  // hoping that this will be a totally new instance,
                       // and the previous set() won't change it at all
```

Okay that code will work the way I wanted. I create two new objects, and their prototype
will be the same still after I called x.set().

```
x.locvar1's value: "ch_locvar1"
x.locvar2's value:  "locvar2"

y.locvar1's value:  "locvar1"
y.locvar2's value:  "locvar2"

their prototypes value: 
locvar1 : "locvar1", 
locvar2 : "locvar2"
```

The problem comes, when I try to use further objects in Class1's field.

```
function Class1(){
   this.locvar1 = {a : "a"};
   this.locvar2 = "locvar2";
}

function Class2(){
    this.set = function(){     
        this.locvar1.a = "ch_locvar1";
    }
} 
Class2.prototype = new Class1;

var x = new Class2();
x.set();

var y = new Class2();
```

That will out:

```
x.locvar1.a's value: "ch_locvar1"
x.locvar2's value:  "locvar2"

what's ok, but..:
y.locvar1.a's value:  "ch_locvar1"
y.locvar2's value:  "locvar2"

their prototypes value: 
locvar1.a : "ch_locvar1", 
locvar2 : "locvar2"
```

So it seems like with the statement "this.locvar1.a" I change the {a : "a"} object's prototype globally, and not a local instance of "this.locvar1"...

Am I sure on this? How can I code around that? I tried to change "this.locvar1 = new {a : "a"};" because this seems logical to me, but the result is the same.

Comment: In javascript objects are passed by reference. This is why in the second example `locvar1` changes.

Comment: I'm not sure what you were expecting to happen...?

Comment: It seems that CoffeeScript compiles this as you expect it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/nfJDk/14/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the prototype inheritance that you were expecting:

```
function Class1(){
   this.locvar1 = {a : "a"};
   this.locvar2 = "locvar2";
}

function Class2(){
    this.__proto__ = new Class1()
    this.set = function(){     
        this.locvar1.a = "ch_locvar1";
    }
} 

var x = new Class2();
x.set();

var y = new Class2();

document.write(x.locvar1.a) // outputs 'ch_locvar1'
document.write('<br />')    
document.write(y.locvar1.a) // outputs 'a'
```

I have set the prototype object to a `new Class1` when `Class2` is instantiated. It doesn't work your way because both Objects will reference the same prototype Object and JavaScript is pass by reference, as others have explained.

Comment: Using `__proto__` should be avoided and does not work in all browsers.

Comment: @Sarfraz Really? I did not know that. How is it possible to do my snippet cross browser then?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082791/javascript-and-proto-what-browsers-use-it

Comment: Thank you. Either `__proto__` or `prototype` then.

Answer (score 1):

`this.locvar1 = new {a : "a"};` is wrong, try `this.locvar1 = {a : "ch_locvar1"};`.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question.