# How to assign a prototype to an already constructed object?

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototypal-inheritance

The following code alerts 'undefined.' Can I make it alert '2' without changing the first three lines?

```
var b = function(){}
b.prototype.c = 2
var a = {}

a.constructor = b
alert(a.c)
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FHLgR/4/

Comment: The internal `[[Prototype]]` is established as an inaccessible property when an object is constructed. The public constructor property is just a convenience that can be set to any value (as you've discovered) and has no effect on the value of `[[Prototype]]`. However, a `__prototype__` property may be introduced in a future version of ECMAScript (see basilikum's answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, but I think it's non-standard and therefore not supported by every browser:

```
a.__proto__ = b.prototype;
```

Comment: I really don't recommend doing this unless you have too. That being said you shouldn't have to. Its not supported by all browsers => http://stackoverflow.com/a/3082878/243568. The docs for __proto__ can be seen here => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto.

Comment: @RobertHurst I'm not saying it's a good idea but it's as far as I know the only way to achieve what he is trying to do. But of course your right.

Comment: I agree with your answer. I'm not critical of it, actually I was about to post the same answer. I just wanted point out how bad an idea this is.

Comment: @RobertHurst absolutely no offense taken. And thanks for pointing it out and for the extra infos in your comment.