# Meaning of JavaScript directive

Tags: javascript

I saw this JavaScript code in some pages a few times:

```
<script>
      document.write('<script src=js/vendor/'
        + ('__proto__' in {} ? 'zepto' : 'jquery')
        + '.js><\/script>');
    </script>
```

I would like to know what exactly it does. I guess it serves to include jquery and zepto libraries.

Comment: It writes `<script src=js/vendor/zepto.js></script>` to the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{}` declares a new object in Javascript, mostly it equals `new Object()`.

`in` operator detects whether the right operand has a member (function, property, etc).

Zepto is lightweight and has the same APIs as jQuery, but it only supports modern browsers. In old browsers like IE6, `__proto__` is not supported, so it falls back to jQuery for compatibility. If browser supports such feature, it loads Zepto instead.

Answer (score 4):

This code appears to be checking for the existence of `__proto__` on objects, and pulling in Zepto if available and jQuery when not. Zepto like to keep their codebase small and as a result only really support modern browsers.

According to [this](https://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part1#Browser-side_Javascript) (under the **browser-side javascript** section) `__proto__` is not supported by all browsers.

Comment: Can you point the relevant point of the page you link to ? What browser doesn't have `__proto__` ?

Comment: updated answer. It was a source taken from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082791/javascript-and-proto-what-browsers-use-it) answer

Comment: OK, so IE8- doesn't seem to have it.

Answer (score 1):

It checks if the browser has `__proto_` as part of its objects, if yes, it includes `zepto.js`, else it includes `jquery.js` I believe that `__proto__` is supported in all major browsers, but there may be a few edge cases

The only browsers that I know of that don't support `__proto__` are IE <= 8 and Opera

Answer (score 1):

there are some browsers (e.g. `IE10-`) which do not support `Zepto`,

so this statement checks if `__proto__` is defined for a browser, if not then `fallback to jQuery`